# My context's function is not defined, I can't call it

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having authentication issues with my context in Next.js

Inside my src folder I have my context in the contexts folder, and in the app folder I have my login screen where I am calling the login function of useAuth(), but when I call it it gives an error, saying that it is not defined.

I'm with next in version 13.4.16

I have my context:

```js
"use client";

import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { User } from '../@types/user';
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';
import api, { defaults } from '../config/api';

interface AuthContextData {
  signed: boolean;
  user: Partial<User> | null;
  Login(user: object): Promise<void>;
  Logout(): void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData);

interface AuthProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
  }

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<Partial<User> | null>({ email: 'teste@localhost.com' });
  const [signed, setSigned] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storagedUser = Cookie.get('@App:user');
    const storagedToken = Cookie.get('@App:accessToken');

    if (storagedToken && storagedUser) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(storagedUser));
      defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${storagedToken}`;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSigned(Boolean(user))
  }, [user])

  async function Login(userData: Partial<User>) {
    try {
      const response = await api.post('auth/login', userData);
      setUser(response.data.user);
      
      defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`;
      
      Cookie.set('@App:user', JSON.stringify(response.data.user));
      Cookie.set('@App:accessToken', response.data.accessToken);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  function Logout() {
    Cookie.remove('@App:user');
    Cookie.remove('@App:accessToken');
    setUser(null);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ signed, user, Login, Logout }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  return context;
}
```

My login screen:

```js
"use client";

import { NextPage } from 'next'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Send } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Button } from '@/components/Button';
import { Input } from '@/components/Input';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

const styles = {
  main:
    "flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen text-white h-screen",
  content: {
    base: "grid gap-10 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 md:divide-x md:divide-gray-600 text-white h-96",
    info: "flex flex-col gap-20 align-right items-end justify-center",
    form: "flex flex-col gap-5 justify-center pl-10"
  },
  text: {
    textInfo: "text-4xl font-bold flex flex-col text-right",
    colorGreen: "text-green-secondary mt-3",
  },
  icon: "text-base"
}

const LoginPage: NextPage = (props) => {
  const { Logout, user } = useAuth()
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    Logout()
  }

  const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.content.base}>
        <div className={styles.content.info}>
          <Image
            src="/images/logo-xgrow.png"
            alt="XGROW"
            width={212}
            height={53}
          />
          <div className={styles.text.textInfo}>
            <span>
              Seja bem vindo à
            </span>
            <span className={styles.text.colorGreen}>
              Área do aluno
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.content.form}>
          <div>
            <span>
              Acesse usando seu e-mail
              { user?.email }
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              label="Email"
              placeholder="Insira seu e-mail de acesso" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button onClick={() => handleLogin()}>
              <Send className={styles.icon}></Send>
              Enviar token de acesso
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Image
              src="/images/site-blindado.png"
              alt="Logo Xgrow"
              width={100}
              height={22}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Error code:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Logout is not a function
    at handleLogin (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/(public)/login/page.tsx:38:9)
    at onClick (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/(public)/login/page.tsx:129:46)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19443:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19492:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19567:29)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19581:25)
    at executeDispatch (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30621:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30653:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30666:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30677:3)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30867:12)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23747:12)
    at batchedUpdates (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27583:12)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30866:3)
    at dispatchEvent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28639:5)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28610:5)
```

Comment: Have you used `<AuthProvider />` in the root component? You need to do that before `useAuth()` returns any value.